# PDO and Multiple Query / Concurrency Issues

Tags: php, database, concurrency, pdo

In PHP I am using PDO to interact with databases. One procedure that commonly takes place consists of multiple queries (several SELECT and UPDATE). This works most of the time, but occasionally the data becomes corrupt where two (or more) instances of the procedure run concurrently.

What is the best way to work around this issue? Ideally I would like a solution which works with the majority of PDO drivers.

Comment: Is this a stored procedure in the database? or do you mean two instances of a PHP script doing the same operations?

Comment: @Marc B, Everything is PHP side, there are no stored procedures at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your database back end supports transactions (mysql with InnoDB, Postgres, etc), then simply wrapping the operation in question in a transaction will solve the problem.  If one instance of the script is in the middle of the transaction when the second scripts attempts to start it, then the second script's database changes will be queued up and not be attempted until the first transaction completes.  This means the database will always be in a valid state provided the transaction starting and committing logic is implemented correctly.

```
if ($inTransaction = $pdo -> beginTransaction ())
{
    // Do your selects and updates here. Try to keep this section as short as possible though, as you don't want to keep other pending transactions waiting
    if ($condition_for_success_met)
    {
        $pdo -> commit ();
    }
    else
    {
        $pdo -> rollback ();
    }
}
else
{
    // Couldn't start a transaction. Handle error here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Do transactions lock the PHP process? The script has to run the transaction and then do something else once it has finished?

Comment: is there a way to do `if ($pdo->supportsTransactions())` before attempting to initiate one?

Comment: it seems as though this has fixed the issue. I am still interested in the above questions though. Thanks !!

Comment: Transactions are handled by the database so they should have no effect on your script. In fact it should improve concurrency because other scripts can continue reading from the database while this one is making changes. There is no supportsTransaction method, but beginTransaction throws a PDOException if the driver doesn't support them so you can catch it and handle the situation as you see fit.  Be warned though: MySQL will allow you to start a transaction on MyISAM tables even though MyISAM doesn't support transactions!

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I wasn't aware of this being a limitation of MyISAM. My server is actually running InnoDB so this isn't too much of an issue for me.